# Is df.mean(axis=1) function dataframe python for all row?

Tags: python, dataframe

In the next code, I want, when in a row value of 0.254 is found, it is not averaged, the value 0.254 is left and it goes to the next row, but it does not work, it averages all the values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'uno': [1, 2, 3], 'dos': [0.254, 5, 6], 'tres': [7, 8, 9]}, index=['x', 'y', 'z'])

df_range = len(df)
for row in df:
    if df[row][i]==0.254:
        df['mean'][i]=0.254
    else:
        df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
print df
```

Do you know where it could be wrong? Maybe in the part:

```
 else:
            df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

But I don't know how to fix it

Thanks!

Comment: Given your input - could you show the desired output? For instance - would it be: `[0.254, 5.   , 6.   ]` or something else?

Comment: Yes! [0.254, 5. , 6. ]

Comment: but output with the code is: [2.751, 5. , 6. ]

Comment: You can probably use `df['mean'] = np.where(df.ne(0.254).all(axis=1), df.mean(axis=1), 0.254)` on your original DF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` to set the mean to 0.254 if any value in that row is 0.254 otherwise set it to the mean of the row itself, eg:

```
df['mean'] = np.where(df.eq(0.254).any(axis=1), 0.254, df.mean(axis=1))
```